# Why does Jenkins only push the parent Maven project to Sonar?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I have a multi-module Maven project looking like this

```
/parent
/module-a
/module-b
```

`parent` acts as aggregator and actual parent project for the modules. I have a Jenkins job that builds parent and a Sonar post-build step without changes to the settings. During the build, which runs from /parent, everything is fine, all the modules are being built. In Sonar however, I only see `parent` afterwards, without any submodules. Why is that so? Is it because of the flat folder structure or is there another reason?

Comment: What happens when you run the sonar analysis without jenkins? Also did you check, if the modules are included as components of "parent"?

Comment: @Casey, if I start sonar from command line, all modules show up in Sonar.  Yes, the modules are included as components, and they are also being built by Maven.

Comment: Could you try to execute the sonar goal with maven instead of using the post-build step? I think Jenkins only looks in the parent project for the relevent files and ignores any relations defined in maven. Do you get any messages that sonar can't find some classes for analysis?

Comment: All Jenkins/Sonar does is create a new pom called sonar-pom.xml in target/sonar, then runs that pom via mvn sonar:sonar.  Given your project is flat, I suspect your Jenkins workspace for the parent project only has one sonar-pom.xml - for the parent, thus it doesn't execute for the children.

Comment: @Casey, if I trigger sonar on my machine with `sonar:sonar` all works fine. It seems that the Jenkins plugin does not like the flat structure as @tdrury suggested.